# App crashes when Home or Back button press

Tags: java, android

So, my app crashes when I press Home button or Back button. I don't know how to solve this issue. Help!!!

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public Game(Context context) {
 super(context);
 getHolder().addCallback(this);
    gameContext = context;
}
...         
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {    
 boolean retry = true;
 updateThread.setRunning(false);
 while (retry) {
 try {updateThread.join();
 retry = false; } 
 catch (InterruptedException e) {
 }
 }
 }
}
```

And here is a log of process when I press Home button:

```
07-15 07:43:47.333: I/ActivityManager(285): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 285
07-15 07:43:47.673: W/WindowManager(285): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (290x515) to layer 21015
07-15 07:43:48.013: D/gralloc(36): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
07-15 07:43:48.043: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008004_00000000 [ 84 ipp] (103 ins) at [0x4296eea0:0x4296f03c] in 599261 ns
07-15 07:43:48.464: D/gralloc(36): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
07-15 07:43:48.504: I/ActivityManager(285): Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h tball/v s.8}
07-15 07:43:48.574: I/InputReader(285): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
07-15 07:43:48.574: I/InputReader(285): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 720x1280, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
07-15 07:43:49.003: I/Choreographer(560): Skipped 168 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 07:43:49.343: D/PhoneStatusBar(560): mSettingsPanelGravity = 55
07-15 07:43:49.593: D/dalvikvm(560): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7091K, 51% free 7087K/14336K, paused 111ms, total 131ms
07-15 07:43:49.743: W/WindowManager(285): Window freeze timeout expired.
07-15 07:43:49.743: W/WindowManager(285): Force clearing orientation change: Window{41ada620 u0 NavigationBar}
07-15 07:43:49.824: I/WindowManager(285): Screen frozen for +2s101ms due to Window{41ada620 u0 NavigationBar}
07-15 07:43:50.194: I/Choreographer(560): Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 07:43:50.803: I/Choreographer(400): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 07:43:51.783: I/Choreographer(400): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 07:43:52.493: I/Choreographer(560): Skipped 194 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-15 07:43:53.105: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(799): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-15 07:43:54.173: D/dalvikvm(285): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3158K, 52% free 5244K/10724K, paused 5ms+11ms, total 134ms
```

Answer (score 0):

try releasing resources which are consuming memory whenever they are in no use and you can do this in onPause() methods

you can also make some changes in manifiest.xml file like this

```
<activity android:name="your.package.name.YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
...
```

Comment: "try releasing resources" - how?? ))) About the 2nd advice - it doesn't work for my app...